# Kong matching routes with same routes in different services

Tags: nginx, kong, kong-plugin

I have two services stored in in kong, both services have the same route name `/myRoute`.

There are two different clients (A and B) which make requests to two different ports (e.g. port 8080 and 8081) I have the [proxy_listen](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/configuration/#proxy_listen) enabled for these two ports so both client can hit the kong service. The issue I am having is when the client A makes a request that is destined for service A, it is getting regex matching to service B.

I have attempted to add the [hosts](https://marcoam-patch-1--kongdocs.netlify.app/2.0.x/proxy/#request-header) attribute in the route object so it could regex match by client's request hosts, this seems to work better, however, this doesn't prevent the client manually changing the host header when making the request. e.g. if client A spoofs the host attribute to try to attempt to access service B API then that would be a security concern.

```
curl -vk https://<service_A_host>:<service_A_port>/myRoute -H "Host: <service_B_host>"
```

I have also tried using the source, [destination](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/proxy/#request-destination) attributes, ideally, this would be the best way to prevent client's manually spoofing the host attribute to try to regex match with other services, but setting this option requires tcp protocol (so http/https won't work).

I was going to look into perhaps there my be a way to configure this in the `nginx.conf` to proxy request coming in from a specific port to a specific service?

Kind of out of ideas and was wondering if there is another way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The different port are not isolated on Kong, two solution to have strong isolation, 2 differents kong deployment or use request destination port to route cf https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/proxy/#request-destination

Comment: As I mentioned above, the request destination only allows tcp, and doesn't work for http or https. Having multiple kong deployments for each port would increase the memory footprint greatly on my box (four services postgres, kong, kong migrations, deck in one docker-compose for each listening port is overkill), as this is not running in a cloud env where memory cannot be scaled .

Comment: "if client A spoofs the host attribute to try to attempt to access service B API then that would be a security concern." How do you prevent client A to use the other port ?
You can lower the config of Kong to have 2 kongs running without issue on ressources

Comment: "How do you prevent client A to use the other port?" We have L2 firewall rules to nat the traffic from source to destination (kong). What do you mean by lowering the config of Kong?

Comment: You say that the memory footprint is too high, you can share postgres. And you can change the nginx default value to decrease the memory usage. The ressources consumption is relative to the traffic